# Secure shell protocol connection

Tags: macos, mac, ssh, macbook-pro, macbook-air

Okay so my client is a Macbook air connecting to a server Macbook Pro and when I type

```
ssh virginiaford@165.228.37.220
```

into Terminal it does not send back any output. After a while it sends this back.

```
connect to host 165.228.37.220 port 22: Operation timed out
```

I have checked that the server's firewall is down and I have allowed all users for remote access in system preferences. I am a noob, please help; This is my first question on Superuser. Lol!

Edit: My clients WiFi is in a restraunt and my server is in my home network WiFi.

Edit: I have run ICMP echo request packets to the server and it responds as normal.

Comment: It depends a great deal on your home network. Most such setups use a router doing network address translation, which acts sort of like a network firewall. If so, you'll need to configure port forwarding for port 22 to your server's private IP address. Also, your ISP might block incoming connections. Also, be sure you have secure passwords on all accounts; password guessing attacks against SSH servers are pretty much constant; if you have any easily guessable passwords, they **will** be found and exploited.